# Angular-BrowerSync-Express Cannot POST from client-side Express back-end route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, gulp, browser-sync

I'm working with an Angular-Gulp-Browsersync-Express app and I'm having trouble getting angular's $http resource to POST a simple "contact us" form to my express server.

Every time I try to submit my form I get the following error:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/submitContactUsForm 404 (Not Found)
Cannot POST /submitContactUsForm
```

To be up front, I've got much more experience working with the front-end than I do with the back-end so it could very well be that I've got the wrong server setup.

Here is my Express Server:

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var http = require('http');
var routes = require('.././src/index.module.js');
// var contactController = require('.././api/http/controllers/contactcontroller.js');

// require database data modeling via mongoose
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Express Session allows us to use Cookies to keep track of
// a user across multiple pages. We also need to be able to load
// those cookies using the cookie parser
var session = require('express-session');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

// Flash allows us to store quick one-time-use messages
// between views that are removed once they are used.
// Useful for error messages.
var flash = require('connect-flash');


// Use express and set it up
var app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/submitContactUsForm', function(req, res) {
console.log('it hit the server');
})

var path = require('path');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var conf = require('./conf');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var browserSyncSpa = require('browser-sync-spa');
var util = require('util');
var proxyMiddleware = require('http-proxy-middleware');

 function browserSyncInit(baseDir, browser) {
  browser = browser === undefined ? 'default' : browser;

 var routes = null;
 if(baseDir === conf.paths.src || (util.isArray(baseDir) && baseDir.indexOf(conf.paths.src) !== -1)) {
 routes = {
  '/bower_components': 'bower_components'
  };
 }

browserSync.instance = browserSync.init({
 startPath: '/',
 cors: true,
 browser: browser,
 port: 8080,
 server: {
  baseDir: baseDir,
  routes: routes,
  middleware: function (req, res, next) {
      res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
      res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, Content-Type, Accept");
      res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT");
      next();
   }
  },
 });
}

browserSync.use(browserSyncSpa({
 selector: '[ng-app]'// Only needed for angular apps
}));

gulp.task('serve', ['setenvconstants','watch'], function () {
 browserSyncInit([path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/serve'), conf.paths.src]);
});

gulp.task('serve:dist', ['setenvconstants','build'], function () {
 browserSyncInit(conf.paths.dist);
});

gulp.task('serve:e2e', ['inject'], function () {
 browserSyncInit([conf.paths.tmp + '/serve', conf.paths.src], []);
});

gulp.task('serve:e2e-dist', ['build'], function () {
 browserSyncInit(conf.paths.dist, []);
});
```

Here is the Angular Controller I am trying to post from:

```
(function() {
 'use strict';

angular
    .module('commonSenseDietApp')
    .controller('ContactController', ContactController);


 function ContactController($http, $log) {
    // controllerAs syntax
    var vm = this;

 vm.contactInfo = {
  email: vm.email
 }

 vm.processContactForm = function() {

  return $http.post('/submitContactUsForm', vm.contactInfo)
      .then(returnSendSuccessful)
      .catch(sendFail);

  function returnSendSuccessful(response) {
    $log.log(response.data);
    return response.data;
  }

  function sendFail(err) {
    return $log.error(err.data);
  }
 }


 }

})();
```

Here are my Client-Side Routes:

```
(function() {
 'use strict';

 angular
 .module('commonSenseDietApp')
 .config(routeConfig);

 function routeConfig($routeProvider) {
 // Home Page
 $routeProvider
 .when('/', {
  templateUrl: 'app/views/pages/home.html',
  controller: 'MainController',
  controllerAs: 'vm'
 })
 .otherwise({
  controller: 'Error404Controller',
  templateUrl: 'app/views/errors/404.html'
 });

 // About Page
 $routeProvider
 .when('/about', {
  templateUrl: 'app/views/static/about.html'
 })
 .otherwise({
  controller: 'Error404Controller',
  templateUrl: 'app/views/errors/404.html'
 });

// Terms of Use Page
$routeProvider
.when('/terms-of-use', {
  templateUrl: 'app/views/static/terms-of-use.html'
})
.otherwise({
  controller: 'Error404Controller',
  templateUrl: 'app/views/errors/404.html'
});

// Privacy Policy Page
$routeProvider
.when('/privacy-policy', {
  templateUrl: 'app/views/static/privacy-policy.html'
})
.otherwise({
  controller: 'Error404Controller',
  templateUrl: 'app/views/errors/404.html'
});

// Contact Us Page
$routeProvider
.when('/contact', {
  templateUrl: 'app/views/pages/contact.html',
  controller: 'ContactController',
  controllerAs: 'vm'
})
.otherwise({
  controller: 'Error404Controller',
  templateUrl: 'app/views/errors/404.html'
});

// Answer Page
$routeProvider
.when('/answer', {
  templateUrl: 'app/views/pages/answer.html',
  controller: 'AnswerController',
  controllerAs: 'vm'
})
.otherwise({
  controller: 'Error404Controller',
  templateUrl: 'app/views/errors/404.html'
});

// How It Works Page
$routeProvider
.when('/how-it-works', {
  templateUrl: 'app/views/static/how-it-works.html'
})
.otherwise({
  controller: 'Error404Controller',
  templateUrl: 'app/views/errors/404.html'
});

 // Algorithm Explainer Page
 $routeProvider
 .when('/meet-ONNA', {
  templateUrl: 'app/views/static/meet-ONNA.html'
 })
 .otherwise({
  controller: 'Error404Controller',
  templateUrl: 'app/views/errors/404.html'
 });
}
})();
```

Here is my contact form markup:

```
<section>
 <div class="contact-us-title">
    <h1>Contact Us</h1>
 </div>

 <form class="contact-us-form" name="contactUsForm" ng-submit="vm.processContactForm()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input placeholder="name" type="text" name="name" ng-model="vm.name" class="form-control" required />
        <span class="label label-danger" ng-show="vm.submitted && contact-us-form.name.$error.required">Required!</span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input placeholder="Email" type="email" name="email" ng-model="vm.email" class="form-control" required />
        <span class="label label-danger" ng-show="vm.submitted && contact-us-form.email.$error.required">Required!</span>
  <span class="label label-danger" ng-show="vm.submitted && contact-us-form.$error.email">Invalid email!</span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input name="headline" placeholder="Headline" type="text" ng-model="vm.headline" class="form-control" required/>
        <span class="label label-danger" ng-show="vm.submitted && contact-us-form.headline.$error.required">Required!</span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message" type="textbox" ng-model="vm.message" class="form-control" required></textarea>
        <span class="label label-danger" ng-show="vm.submitted && contact-us-form.subjectList.$error.required">Required!</span>
    </div>


    <input type="submit" id="submit-contact-form-btn">
  </form>
</section>
```

I'm also not seeing anything logging to console in the terminal. Any insight on this would be super helpful and very appreciated.

Comment: Does `console.log('it hit the server');` appear (in the terminal where you're running node) when you attempt the POST request from the browser?

Comment: Just checked and no that doesn't print to the terminal currently

Answer (score 0):

Eureka I found the answer!

Turns out my lack of experience with express playing nice with browersync was certainly a hinderance for me here. The answer lied in Proxying browsersync to express and the use of [gulp-nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-nodemon) package. After some restructuring I've got the right setup:

My Browser-Sync server and gulp init tasks:

```
'use strict';

var path = require('path');
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
var gulp = require('gulp');
var conf = require('./conf');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var browserSyncSpa = require('browser-sync-spa');
var util = require('util');
var proxyMiddleware = require('http-proxy-middleware');
var nodemon = require('gulp-nodemon');
var reload = browserSync.reload;

function browserSyncInit(baseDir, browser) {

 var routes = null;
 if(baseDir === conf.paths.src || (util.isArray(baseDir) && baseDir.indexOf(conf.paths.src) !== -1)) {
  routes = {
   '/bower_components': 'bower_components'
  };
 }

 browserSync.instance = browserSync.init({
  startPath: '/',
  cors: true,
  browser: browser = browser === undefined ? 'default' : browser,
  proxy: 'http://localhost:8081',
  port: port
 // https: true
 });
}

browserSync.use(browserSyncSpa({
 selector: '[ng-app]' // Only needed for angular apps
}));

// Run Gulp tasks
gulp.task('serve', ['browser-sync','setenvconstants','watch']);

gulp.task('browser-sync', ['nodemon'], function () {
 browserSyncInit([path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/serve'),   conf.paths.src]);
});
gulp.task('serve:dist', ['setenvconstants','build'], function () {
 browserSyncInit(conf.paths.dist);
});
gulp.task('serve:e2e', ['inject'], function () {
 browserSyncInit([conf.paths.tmp + '/serve', conf.paths.src], []);
});
gulp.task('serve:e2e-dist', ['build'], function () {
 browserSyncInit(conf.paths.dist, []);
});
gulp.task('nodemon', [], function(done) {
 var running = false;

 return nodemon({
  script: 'api/app.js',
  watch: ['api/**/*.*', 'src/**/*.*']
 })
 .on('start',function() {
  if (!running) {
    done();
  }
  running = true;
 })
 .on('restart', function() {
  setTimeout(function(){
    reload();
  }, 500);
 });
});
```

My Express server:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var http = require('http');
var port = process.env.PORT || 8081;
var cors = require('cors');
var path = require('path');
var publicRoutes = require('./http/routes/web.js');

// require database data modeling via mongoose
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Express Session allows us to use Cookies to keep track of
// a user across multiple pages. We also need to be able to load
// those cookies using the cookie parser
var session = require('express-session');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

// Flash allows us to store quick one-time-use messages
// between views that are removed once they are used.
// Useful for error messages.
var flash = require('connect-flash');

// Use Express and set it up
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
// Parse requests to JSON
app.use(bodyParser.json({type: '*/*', limit: '50mb'}));
// set Jade as the view engine
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
// tell server where to find our views
app.set('views', __dirname + '/.././src/app/views');
// make sure bower components are installed.
app.use('/underscore',    express.static(path.resolve('.././node_modules/underscore')));
// tell our server where to find static assets depending on the environment.
process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production' ?  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/../..'))) :  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/.././dist')));
// enable cors
app.use(cors({
 "origin": "*",
 "methods": "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
 "allowedHeaders": ["Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"],
 "preflightContinue": false
}));

// Pull in our public routes
app.use('/api', publicRoutes);

// Listen
app.listen(port, function(error) {
 if (error) {
  console.error(error);
 } else {
  console.info("==>   Listening on port %s. Visit http://localhost:%s/ in your browser.", port, port);
 }
});
```

I'm now able to $http.post from my Angular controller considering the route prefix in my express server:

```
vm.processContactForm = function() {

  return $http.post('/api/submitContactUsForm', vm.contactInfo)
      .then(returnSendSuccessful)
      .catch(sendFail);

  function returnSendSuccessful(response) {
    $log.log(response);
    // return response.data;
  }

  function sendFail(err) {
    return $log.error(err.data);
  }
}
```

The only issue I'm having now is with...

```
process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production' ? app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/.././src'))) : app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/.././dist')));
```

wherein '/dist' is served just fine but '/src' only serves a blank index.html page to my localhost. I'll post this as a new question and consider this issue solved. Thanks for the help!